# Decorators ul li zend_form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-decorators

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
<ul>
<div>
<fieldset id="fieldset-groups"><legend>Endereço</legend>

    <li>
        <label for="name" class="optional">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
            <div class="errors">
                    <p>Error</p>
            </div>
    </li>

</fieldset>   

</div>
</ul>
</form>
```

How do I make my way the code above, using the decorator zend?

Comment: Have you tried making your own decorators? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Also this is not valid HTML. You cannot have a div as a direct child of a ul, or a li as a child of fieldset. You'll need to at least wrap the div in an li and put another ul side the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way:

> ```
>     $this->addDecorator('FormElements')
>          ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'ul'))
>          ->addDecorator('Form');
>     $this->setElementDecorators( array(
>                                     'ViewHelper',
>                                     'Label',
>                                     'Errors',
>                                     new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag' => 'li')) 
>                                 ));
>     $this->setDisplayGroupDecorators( array(
>                                         'FormElements',
>                                         'Fieldset',
>                                         'FormErrors',
>                                          new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag' => 'li')),
>                                       ));
> ```

The problem is that I need to float the label and text elements, so I tried to use a list.

This was the only way I could.